# Why can I only download a file when I navigate to the API call directly?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using the [excel-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-export) package to allow the user to download an Excel file.  I put the logic in an API call to `/api/Excel`.  If I navigate in the url bar directly to `localhost:3000/api/Excel`, the file downloads.  However, if I make an http call in Angular `$http.get('api/Excel');`, the console shows a successful response but nothing downloads.

I have similar Angular API calls throughout my application which all work perfectly (when downloading files aren't involved).

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Is your website running on a different port?

Comment: You can't download the result of an XHR request to the user's machine. Just supply a link directly to download the file

Comment: What content type are you sending ?

Comment: I think that is because, the direct request from your browser, gets the right server response, and your browser interprets that response as a file stream and based on the headers, triggers a download of the Excel file....if you do an async call to the url-method, your browser doesn't knows what are you doing or how to interprets it :)